# How do I solve and write this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, select, case

I have three tables that look sort of like this:

Table1 has 1 row of numbers:

```
123
124
125
126
127
```

etc.

Table2 is similar to Table1, but has more elements:

```
123
124
125
158
152
175
```

etc.

Main table has many rows and here is where I struggle:

```
select
   a,
   b,
   c,
   if HIT in Table1 and NO HIT in Table2 then '1G'
   else if HIT in Table1 AND HIT in Table2 then '2G'
   else d,
   e,
   f,
   g,
   etc
from Table3
```

Sort of messy explained, but I don't know how to say it better... Sorry!

Hope some of you guys can help me with this issue!

-Geir A.

Comment: "Table1 has 1 row of numbers:" row? or column? give appropriate sample. Also please add your desired output from them.

Comment: "main table" is Table3? You want all rows in Table3 and some sort of computed value based on "hits" in the other tables? And by "hits" you mean that a row exists based on matching which columns?

Comment: @mkRabbani: 1 column and many rows, correct.. My head was spinning when I wrote it

Comment: @SMor: I am very bad at explaining, but I want to specify text for that specific column if a value exists in a and not b, and then another if in both a and b. If no such value exists, then use what ever value is in that column from previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two `LEFT JOIN`. For example:

```
select
  a,
  b,
  c,
  case when b.col is not null and c.col is null then '1G'
       when b.col is not null and c.col is not null then '2G'
       else d end,
  e,
  f,
  g,
  etc
from table3 a
left join table1 b on b.col = a.col
left join table2 c on c.col = a.col
```